# How do I stop a div from loading accidentally on first page load?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I have a content navigation bar for my website which is supposed to show only after the user has scrolled 800px down the page. I'm using this JS code to implement this behaviour:

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (y > 800) {
    $("#pn-navigation-bar").fadeIn();
  } else {
    $("#pn-navigation-bar").fadeOut();
  }
});
```

However, whenever the page initially loads the navigation bar still shows up but disappears after the user scrolls a little. This is demonstrated in [this](https://gofile.io/d/PffujI) video here and the images below:

[image]
[image]

But the JS code specifies not to show the div before a certain amount has been scrolled. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logic doesn't specify "*not to show the div before a certain amount has been scrolled*" but rather, it specifies something more like "*when the page is scrolled, hide the div if a certain amount has not been scrolled.*" So you need to also specify the initial visibility of the nav bar, once the page has been loaded but before any scroll has happened.

Just set `style="display:none;"` on your `#pn-navigation-bar` to hide it initially.

or  `$("#pn-navigation-bar").hide()` in your document ready if you don't want to change the css.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, that does make sense. I tried editing the css to `display = none;` like you said, but it still appears on page load. Can you possibly add the document ready code to your answer as well? I'm not familiar with Javascript and don't really know where it goes.

Comment: I'm currently adding this before the closing body tag:  `$( document ).ready(function() { $("#pn-navigation-bar").hide(); });` Should this go in the header instead?

Comment: it shouldnt really matter where it goes. If that isnt hiding it, try changing the style to `"display:none !important;"`